# How to restore my latop using shadow copy

Tags: system-restore, shadow-copy

In the past hours my laptop is always getting BSOD with the problem on BSCSISDA.sys, so it tried to update the driver, but before updating the driver i tried to create a restore point. But while creating restore point it crashed again. now when i checked the restore point it say that there is no restore point created. So i checked the system protection and clicked the configure button and found there is still 30GB usage for the restore point.

I also check it using command "vssadmin list shadows" and the shadow copy for the past month is still there.

How I can recover back those shadow copy? I really need to restore my laptop. The latest successfull restore point created is on august 1 base on the list on vssadmin.

clean install is not my option for now.

Comment: Do a Win key +R, then type in rstrui.exe, this will open system restore.

Comment: My storage is fine no bad sector, the bsod is caused by the sd card i inserted. and it was just happened this morning. as far as i know restore point uses the shadow copy, my problem is the shadow copy is still there but the restore point didn't find it i think it was caused when i create a restore point and it crashed and it got out of sync.

Comment: @Moab yeah, but the problem is it didn't list the other previous restore points

Comment: @Ramhound So do you have any good suggestion? Actually what i need is the previous version file on the appdata folder, to restore the setting of the some of my software i used. I will not use the the shadow copy to restore system files because they are all good.

Comment: Any reason why it gets down voted? see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To someone else that will face the same problem as mine, I used [ShadowExplorer](http://www.shadowexplorer.com/) to browse the file inside of the shadow copies.

It has just a minimal interface and you can choose what shadow copy you want to open.